# The qsort isn't fully sorting everything

Tags: c, sorting, struct

I want to sort through all elements but qsort isn't fully sorting everything.

If I had the dates

```
01/01/2019 15:30
01/01/2019 11:15
01/01/2019 17:00
01/01/2019 15:45
01/01/2019 15:30
01/01/2019 08:00
```

And I know for a fact that the values are properly given in the struct

```c
struct Date{ int year, month, day, hour, minute; }

function(...){ //properly assigns values to Date array }

int comp(const void *t1, const void *t2){
    int t1year = ((const struct Date*)t1)->year;
    int t2year = ((const struct Date*)t2)->year;
    int t1month = ((const struct Date*)t1)->month;
    int t2month = ((const struct Date*)t2)->month;
    int t1day = ((const struct Date*)t1)->day;
    int t2day = ((const struct Date*)t2)->day;
    int t1hour = ((const struct Date*)t1)->hour;
    int t2hour = ((const struct Date*)t2)->hour;
    int t1minute = ((const struct Date*)t1)->minute;
    int t2minute = ((const struct Date*)t2)->minute;

    if (t1year < t2year) 
        return -1; 
    if (t1year == t2year && t1month < t2month) 
        return -1; 
    if (t1year == t2year && t1month == t2month && 
    t1day < t2day) 
        return -1;
    if (t1year == t2year && t1month == t2month && 
    t1day == t2day && t1hour < t2hour)
        return -1;
    if (t1year == t2year && t1month == t2month && 
    t1day == t2day && t1hour == t2hour && t1minute < t2minute)
        return -1;
    if (t1year == t2year && t1month == t2month && 
    t1day == t2day && t1hour == t2hour && t1minute == t2minute)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
void sortArray(struct Date dates[], int n){
        qsort(dates, n, sizeof(Date), comp);
}
...

//prints through a for loop until n
```

The results were sorted except for those two that had same time.

```
01/01/2019 08:00
01/01/2019 15:30
01/01/2019 11:15    
01/01/2019 15:30
01/01/2019 15:45
01/01/2019 17:00
```

Comment: Your `comp` function returns the wrong value for two equal times.

Comment: Rather than assigning 10 local variables in the comparison function, use `int comp(const void *vp1, const void *vp2){
    const struct Date*t1 = vp1;
    const struct Date*t2 = vp2;` and then use `if (t1->year < t2->year) return -1 else if (t1->year > t2->year) return +1; else if (t1->month < t2->month) return -1;  … else return 0;` (which also fixes the residual problem of returning the wrong value on equality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison function for `qsort` should return -1 if the first value is less, 1 if the second value is less, and 0 if both are equal.  You're not returning 0 in any of the cases, so you're not returning the proper value for that case.

Rather than building up bigger and bigger conditions to catch the less-than cases, go back and forth checking the most significant fields and working down to the least significant ones.  Also, rather that create a large number of temp variables, create two pointers of the correct type and then use those.

```
int comp(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    const struct Date *t1 = v1;
    const struct Date *t2 = v2;

    if (t1->year < t2->year) {
        return -1; 
    } else if (t1->year > t2->year) {
        return 1; 
    } else if (t1->month < t2->month) {
        return -1; 
    } else if (t1->month > t2->month) {
        return 1; 
    } else if (t1->day < t2->day) {
        return -1; 
    } else if (t1->day > t2->day) {
        return 1; 
    } else if (t1->hour < t2->hour) {
        return -1; 
    } else if (t1->hour > t2->hour) {
        return 1; 
    } else if (t1->minute < t2->minute) {
        return -1; 
    } else if (t1->minute > t2->minute) {
        return 1; 
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```